# Stop form submit when click upload with bootstrap-file-input

Tags: javascript, forms, input

I want to be able to wrap a [bootstrap file input](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/demo) in an normal form and when i click upload (which is a submit button) i want the file to be uploaded normally and not submit the parent form.
This would be easy if i could remove the file bootstrap file input from inside the form , but unfortunately i see no way of removing it.
Example code

```js
$(function(){
  $("#file").fileinput({
      uploadUrl:"\UploadTargetLink"
    });
  
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/4.3.1/js/fileinput.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/4.3.1/css/fileinput.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form name="mainForm" action="\SomeAction">
  <input type="file" name="fileUpload" id="file"/>
  
  </form>
```

I would consider any type of hacks at this time to make this work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

html and plugin call:

```
        $uploadElement.fileinput({
            uploadUrl: '/module/perfrev/ajax-evidence-upload', 
            uploadAsync: true,
            maxFileCount: 10,
            multiple: true,
            uploadExtraData: {userReviewID:plugin.settings.userReviewID}
        })
```

html:
            "
                   id=""
                   class="file file-loading"
                   />

in fileinput.js change _upload click function to add return false then it does not submit:
    _uploadClick: function (e) {

```
        var self = this, $btn = self.$container.find('.fileinput-upload'), $form,
            isEnabled = !$btn.hasClass('disabled') && isEmpty($btn.attr('disabled'));
        if (e && e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            return;
        }
        if (!self.isUploadable) {
            if (isEnabled && $btn.attr('type') !== 'submit') {
                $form = $btn.closest('form');
                // downgrade to normal form submit if possible
                if ($form.length) {
                    $form.trigger('submit');
                }
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            return;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        if (isEnabled) {
            self.upload();
            return false;  //here is change
        }
    },
```